# How to wrap Objective-C, to be called from Python?

Tags: python, objective-c, wrapper, scripting-bridge

I have created an objective-C framework that I would like to import and access through a python script.  I understand how to import this stuff in Python, but what do i need to do on the obj-c side to make that framework importable?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use [PyObjC](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/), as Chuck said. Specifically, I'd suggest getting the [source](http://svn.red-bean.com/pyobjc/trunk/), which contains a collection of scripts, pyobjc-metadata (here's the [readme](http://svn.red-bean.com/pyobjc/trunk/pyobjc/pyobjc-metadata/ReadMe.txt)), that doesn't seem to be included in the default Apple installation, for wrapping a framework, generating the metadata the Python side needs, and so forth.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use [PyObjC](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/), which is included in Mac OS X 10.5 and later.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this particular combination works, but you might be able to use [SWIG](http://swig.org/) to create a Python module out of your Objective-C which can then be imported into Python.